# NULL value for LocalDateTime JPA 2.2 - PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.2

I am not able to set the null value for the field described below. I want to insert NULL as the default value.

```
@Column(name = "answer_date",columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime answerDate
```

When I set the NULL, it shows the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "answer_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying
```

I am using EclipseLink as JPA implementation.

Comment: You did `answerDate = null;`? (I tend to use "DATETIME", though that should not be relevant.)

Comment: Yes, I did manually. But, null is already the default value in java. The problem is occurring while performing DB actions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a known issue. Refer links

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535431 - Bug raised
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546312 - Bug Fixed
- https://www.postgresql.org/messageid/200412101610.16959.scrawford%40pinpointresearch.com
- https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2290

(typeorm also faces the same issue).

> Yes the error message comes from the postgres jdbc driver. The reason
> for this error is eclipselink using varchar as datatype for the 'null'
> value. Other drivers might or might not ignore this wrong datatype,
> the postgres driver does not.

When you try to set the answerDate to null, it turns into a "null" string which is submitted to the postgres database and causes this error since "null" is not a valid timestamp format.

Its better if you assign a default value in case the LocalDateTime is not present.

```
private LocalDateTime answerDate = LocalDateTime.now();
```

In this case, this error message saying "is of type timestamp ... but
expression is of type text.." can be avoided.

**UPDATE**
The error is fixed in eclipseLink version 2.7.6 (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/pull/415)

Comment: But, I don't want to set the current date as a default value. Because this field is used to know when it is answered. It should be null when object is created. Then it can be updated on the next time.

Comment: I tried your problem in my local by setting timestamp explicitly as null but it is working for me. I am using the dependency 
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.2.0.RELEASE and in application.properties, my jpa dialect is 
        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did you use LocalDateTime as java object type? I am using eclipseLink instead of Hibernate :/

Comment: I used java.time.LocalDateTime itself. But I am using spring-data-jpa. I am not familiar with eclipseLink. Let me check and see if there is any solution.

Comment: Please see this link : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535431 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546312. I think it was a known issue as in typeorm. The second link says eclipseLink version 2.7.6 has fixed this problem. Can you update the version of eclipseLink and try?

Comment: I am using EclipseLink 2.7.6. It is really interesting. Because if **columnDefinition** is removed, NULL value is saved successfully. But then, it uses timezone which leads to a parsing problem in the reading.

Comment: Sorry I could not come up with a definite fix for this. The comments in the above pull requests and bugs says that it fixes the issue for the "TIMESTAMP" column definitions. But seeing this as a Postgres JDBC driver issue, can you try updating that also?

Comment: Thanks for your support. But, It is not a good idea to update JDBC and configure again. I will try to use it without timestamp and parse it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for somebody.
I had the same error (I used EclipseLink, Websphere and PostgreSQL).
After update EclipseLink to 2.7.8 I have continued to get the same error.
After the several hours of search I found the following solution:

Add property to **dataSource** in **server.xml**

```
stringType="unspecified"
```

or set `stringType=unspecified` as query parameter to Postgres URL